# is await TaskRun(() => PublicVoidNotAsycMethod) equivalent to PublicVoidNotAsycMethod()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have an `async` method:

```
public async void BillSubscriptions()
{
   await Task.Run(() => ProcessSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
   await Task.Run(() => ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
   await Task.Run(() => ProcessTrialSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
}
```

Note that `ProcessSubscriptions`, `ProcessNonRecurringSUbscriptions` and `ProcessTrialSUbscriptions` are private void methods and not async.

All of those method retrieve data from database and process it and update the database based on some algorithms.

My question is, is the above code equivalent to this code below?

```
public async void BillSubscriptions()
{
   ProcessSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository);
   ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository);
   ProcessTrialSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository);
}
```

Comment: Equivalent in what regard?

Comment: i mean the code below is normal synchronous calls running in the same Thread of the BillSubscriptions Method. my question is the above call is also asynchronous calls running in different threads but because of the await is acting synchronously?

Comment: another question, Why would i use the above code and not the below code, what is the benefit for me using the code above?

Comment: @NadeemTabbaa: I believe the core misunderstanding is around `async` and threads. Simply put, *`async` does **not** run code on a background thread*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are **not** the same at all.

In your first example you have the following:

```
public async void BillSubscriptions()
{
   await Task.Run(() => ProcessSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
   await Task.Run(() => ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
   await Task.Run(() => ProcessTrialSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
}
```

An `async void` method namely `BillSubscriptions`. This method is `public`, as such it can be invoked by anyone. It internally awaits three `private` methods in a specific order. The methods are instructed to run via the `Task.Run` function which in this case accepts a lambda expression that resolves to the `Action` delegate. These methods are executed sequentially and queued to run on a **ThreadPool** thread, a `Task` object is returned to represent the asynchronous operation.

See `Task.Run` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) for details on its functionality.

The other operation is as follows:

```
public async void BillSubscriptions()
{
   ProcessSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository);
   ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository);
   ProcessTrialSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository);
}
```

Again we have a `public` method marked as `async` named `BillSubscriptions` that executes three `private` methods that are executed sequentially. The difference is that these are all ran on the current thread and are blocking. Whereas in the previous example the code does not block and they could potentially (are are likely) to execute on different threads. I have made some modifications to demonstrate the differences:

[Here is the link for the .NET fiddle that will hopefully make this more clear.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MX4Nc8)

Here is the output:

```
Is async = True, ProcessSubscriptions :: Thread ID10
Is async = True, ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions :: Thread ID11
Is async = True, ProcessTrialSubscriptions :: Thread ID10
Is async = False, ProcessSubscriptions :: Thread ID9
Is async = False, ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions :: Thread ID9
Is async = False, ProcessTrialSubscriptions :: Thread ID9
```

**Note:**

1. Avoid using `async void` as it breaks the `async` state machine
2. Since the methods are `private` to the class, make then `async` instead. Rename them to suffix them with `MethodNameAsync`, make them `Task` returning and within their body have them return `Task.Run(() => { ... });`

Since it appears that you are looking to understand if there is an advantage to having `async` code there is...very much so in fact. Since the three `private` methods do not need to wait for the return value of another, they could all run in parallel. You could use `Task.WhenAll` to see a dramatic performance gain. For example if each method took nearly 1 second to execute, that would take at least 3 seconds for them to run **synchronously**, however, if executing in parallel -- it would only take as long as the longest execution of the three.

Comment: very intersting information thanks, i got it, it has a clear and detaild information, and yes you have answered my concern

Answer (score 0):

If your methods are doing database calls then you should use `async await` all the way down (`ToListAsync()`, `db.SaveChangesAsync()` in case you are using EF) and not wrap them in Task.Run(). The reason why you would want to do that is that thread is not blocked while waiting on I/O-Bound operation (DB call in this case) to complete and can be assigned to do something else (for example process another HTTP request in case of web app).

Comment: i understand your answer and that is reasonable in case of i want the IO operation to async, but regardless this, is the await Task.Run() is behaving as calling the method directly?? and the only difference that in await Task.Run is now running fake async calls in different thread but in reality it is acting like normal synchronous call?

Comment: or you can say, why would I use the above code , what it will benefit me?

Comment: "is the await Task.Run() is behaving as calling the method directly??" No, calling method directly will block calling thread until method completes. If you await task then thread is not blocked, it can do something else and the execution of your code will resume when the task is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference.

In your first example, you execute the `Process` methods concurrently on different threads and await each in turn.
Depending on your execution context (e.g. ASP.NET or a XAML app) the `BillSubscriptions` method may continue to run on the main thread (as you are not using `ConfigureAwait(false)`) or it may be continued on some thread pool thread that executed the `Process` method.

In the second example, you just execute synchronously. There is less scheduling and task / context switching going on.
Unless I'm mistaken this version won't work as you are not `awaiting` anything, so it can't be `async`.

The `async` keyword alone won't do anything for you in this case anyway, as `async` methods **run synchronously** until they reach the first `await`.

If you wanted to perform all 3 operations without blocking you have 3 options:

1. make the `Process` methods async and await them (without `Task.Run`)
2. use your second version without the `async` keyword and start it with `Task.Run(() => BillSubscriptions())`
3. if the `Process` methods don't have to be executed in order and can run concurrently you could modify your first version to this:

.

```
public async void BillSubscriptions()
{
   await Task.WhenAll(
      Task.Run(() => ProcessSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
      Task.Run(() => ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
      Task.Run(() => ProcessTrialSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository))
   );
}
```

Comment: very intersting information thanks, i got it, it has a clear and detaild information, and yes you have answered my concern.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, not. But if you worry only about execution order, `BillSubscriptions#2` is equivalent to `BillSubscriptions#1`. Thats because code after wait is added to [Task.ContinueWith method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx)

Without `async/await` `BillSubscriptions` would looks like:

```
public void BillSubscriptions()
{
    Task t1 = Task.Run(() => ProcessSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
    t1.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() => ProcessNonRecurringSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
        t2.ContinueWith(tt =>
        {
            Task.Run(() => ProcessTrialSubscriptions(_subscriptionRepository));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: There **are** differences and the TPL example is misleading.